# Modifying ggplot2 Y axis to use integers without enforcing an upper limit

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am trying to modify the axes in ggplot2 so that it is one decimal point and has a label for every integer. However, I want to do it without an upper limit so that it will automatically adjust to data of different counts.

The difference between my question and the [question posed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622001/how-to-display-only-integer-values-on-an-axis-using-ggplot2) (that I was flagged as being a duplicate of) is that I need to make this work automatically for many different data sets, not just for a single one. It must automatically choose the upper limit instead of creating a fixed y-axis with `breaks=(0,2,4,...)`. This question has been answered extremely well by @DidzisElferts below.

Here is my work:

```
library(data.table)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars <- data.table(mtcars)
mtcars$Cylinders <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
mtcars$Gears <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)
setkey(mtcars, Cylinders, Gears)
mtcars <- mtcars[CJ(unique(Cylinders), unique(Gears)), .N, allow.cartesian = TRUE]

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=Cylinders, y = N, fill = Gears)) + 
               geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
               ylab("Count") + theme(legend.position="top") + 
               scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image: Cylinder Graph]

As you can see, ggplot2 is plotting the axes with a decimal point and doing it every 2.5 automatically. I'd like to change that. Any way to do so?

Comment: I don't think you're going to get around having to infer specific break points/maximum y values from each data set you plot in order to do this.

Comment: That requires far more interaction than I'd like. I was hoping that there is a way to do what I need it to do but it will automatically set an upper limit and then add in axis lines from there.

Comment: @joran see my answer for a solution

Comment: @Jaap Your solution perfectly illustrates the correctness of my comment, namely that either specifying the breaks directly or calculating the max y value for each data set will likely be necessary.

Comment: @joran You're right. When I read your comment again, I see your point. I probably jumped to fast to a conclusion after first reading (which was probably a bit to fast & superficial)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,2,4,6,8,10))`. So your plotting code will look like:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=Cylinders, y = N, fill = Gears)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  ylab("Count") + theme(legend.position="top") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,2,4,6,8,10)) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

---

EDIT: Alternatively you can use `scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(round(max(mtcars$N),0)))` in order to automatically adjust the scale to the maximum value of the y-variable. When you want the breaks more then 1 from each other, you can use for example `seq(from=0,to=round(max(mtcars$N),0),by=2)`

Comment: I saw that in the `scale_y_continuous` documentation. I was hoping to find another way where I don't have to manually define the axis for each plot.

Comment: I tried out using the `scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12))` command and found that `ggplot2` actually still adjusts to the proper upper limit, even if you set y limits that are too high.

Comment: @black_sheep07 but it probably doesn't do that when you set the y-limit to low; in that case my second method work better. I tested it on a plot I made this morning and on that plot it worked.

Comment: True. Would there be any way to round it to the next even number?

Comment: you might try `seq(from=0,to=round(max(mtcars$N),0),by=2)`

Answer (score 4):

```
integer_breaks <- function(x)
  seq(floor(min(x)), ceiling(max(x)))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=Cylinders, y = N, fill = Gears)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  ylab("Count") + theme(legend.position="top") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=integer_breaks) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```