# Tick division and labels causing confusion in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I plot the example below the x-axis labels are confusing since the ticks labeled 2008 and 2012 are 2008.5 and 20012.5. I fiddled and realized that the number format gets truncated because it's so long. What's a good way to floor the ticks and labels?

```
library(ggplot2)
foo <- data.frame(x=2005:2014,y=rnorm(10))
p1 <- ggplot(data = foo, aes(x = x, y = y))
p1 <- p1 + geom_point(size=4)
p1
```

EDIT: THis is indeed a duplicate question:
[How to display only integer values on an axis using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622001/how-to-display-only-integer-values-on-an-axis-using-ggplot2)

My apologies.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This two options could be an idea....

option 1:

```
    foo <- data.frame(x=2005:2014,y=rnorm(10))
    p1 <- ggplot(data = foo, aes(x = x, y = y))
    p1 <- p1 + geom_point(size=4)
    p1 <- p1 + scale_x_continuous(breaks = foo$x)
    p1
```

option 2:

```
    foo <- data.frame(x=2005:2014,y=rnorm(10))
    p1 <- ggplot(data = foo, aes(x = x, y = y))
    p1 <- p1 + geom_point(size=4)
    p1 <- p1 + scale_x_continuous(breaks = foo$x[seq(1, length(foo$x), 2)])
    p1
```