# How do I adjust the decimal places of a ggplot axis label?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made this plot with the following code:

```
A %>% 
  drop_na(Roadgroup) %>% 
  drop_na(L.Share) %>% 
  filter(L.Share != "#DIV/0!")  %>% 

  ggplot(aes(x=LP.share, y=L.Share, colour=Ward)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtT9Q.png]

How would I go about making the y axis labels match the format of the x axis? (with both 2 decimal places, and less densely cluttered)

Comment: Several answers worth reading here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622001/how-to-display-only-integer-values-on-an-axis-using-ggplot2

Comment: It looks like your y-axis variable is a factor. Without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that's just a guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify this with a function inside `scale_y_continuous` with the `breaks` argument:

```
A %>% 
  drop_na(Roadgroup) %>% 
  drop_na(L.Share) %>% 
  filter(L.Share != "#DIV/0!")  %>% 

  ggplot(aes(x=LP.share, y=L.Share, colour=Ward)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = function(y) seq(floor(min(y, digits = 1)), 
                                              ceiling(max(y, digits = 1)), 
                                              by = 0.05))
```

You may need to modify my `function(y)` here to fit your needs (by changing `digits`, and `by`).  However, if `A$L.Share` is a factor, you will need to convert this to a numeric in order for `scale_y_continuous` to work properly.

Comment: Thanks, this worked but as @Camille mentioned the problem was more that the numerical variable was imported in the wrong format as a character not numeric.