# Why doesn't the x axis add value to the existing values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to have a plot

This is my data

```
data <- structure(list(year = c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2020, 2021), n = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 12L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 10L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), groups = structure(list(year = c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I plot it like this

```r
data %>% ggplot(aes(year, n))
```

if you look at the x axis, it adds .0 , 0.5 ... ,
I dont want those .0 etc, can someone comment?

Comment: Have a look at the ```breaks``` argument of ```scale_x_continuous```

Comment: @Sam Yes didn't do the job

Comment: You could instead treat the years as factors if you want them discrete, e.g. data %>% ```ggplot(aes(as.factor(year), n))```

Comment: Many methods at this dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15622001/903061